# What is the most efficient way to poll Azure's service bus as part of a healthcheck?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

We have a requirement to provide an API endpoint which reports the health of various external dependencies. One of these is an Azure Service Bus. By *health* we simply need to know if the service is available and responding to connections.

Our application already starts up a service bus endpoint on startup and uses this to publish messages to its queue. However, it looks like the only way I can test this endpoint's health would be to actually publish a message to the queue and check for errors. I'd rather not do this because having to clean up these message later feels like overkill.

My other idea was to use a dedicated class to create a new endpoint and start it. Then stop it again if there are no errors, as below. And do this each time I need to check the health.

```
// Build the service bus configuration - connection string etc.
var configuration = _configurationBuilder.Configure(_settings);

IEndpointInstance serviceBusEndpoint = null;

try
{
    serviceBusEndpoint = await Endpoint.Start(configuration);

    return true;
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
finally
{
    if (serviceBusEndpoint != null)
    {
        await serviceBusEndpoint.Stop();
    }
}
```

However, I suspect this may be a less efficient approach. Is there a better/correct way to achieve this aim?

Comment: Did you consider setting up [monitoring activity log alerts on service notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-activity-log-alerts-on-service-notifications) ? The [pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/) seems reasonable and provides vast majority of options from sms/email -> azure app push notifications/webhooks. To be honest I didn't try this approach, so hard for me to comment if this is better approach.

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting idea. However, my task is to provide a realtime status of various external services on demand. It may be possible to use these activity alerts to inform this but it'd never quite be a live status. I'm still interested in a specific answer to my question but thank you for helping me think outside the box.

Comment: Is `Endpoint.Start` your abstraction around Azure Service Bus or a framework of some sort?

Comment: Endpoint is part of the NServiceBus assembly

Comment: I am considering using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicclient.schedulemessageasync?view=azure-dotnet, ...although if I were to Schedule a message hours in advance and then Cancel that message, that would constitute two billable operations, I guess at as operations are low cost it may not be a concern.